# Which NIC have the IP address?

Tags: linux, networking, arp

If I have two NICs where I know the MAC addresses.

Without logging into the server, how do I figure out which have the IP address `10.10.10.10`?

Can `arp` somehow be used for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you're on the same subnet as 10.10.10.10, ping the address, then run `arp -a`. That should show your local arp table, including the IP->MAC mapping you're looking for.

Comment: Spot on answer. If you are NOT in the same subnet it can't be done from the outside. You will have to logon to the server itself in that case.

Comment: If the NIC receives its IP address via DHCP, the DHCP server would also have an IP/MAC mapping.